# Is there a way to increase the upload limit wtih the nginx charm?

Tags: juju, nginx, wordpress

Am using Wordpress in Juju Cloud.....When trying to upload a Theme of more than 500 kb...its showing  "413 Request Entity Too Large"   nginx/1.1.19  ..

I just followed the following process to install WordPress on Juju   "https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/"

is there any solution to increase the uploading limit.....I searched for the nginx.conf...but its not there on /etc   or in /var/local

Comment: What Nginx charm are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Okay I've looked at the [Nginx](http://manage.jujucharms.com/~imbrandon/precise/nginx) charm. It appears it puts the config in the default locations. These are `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` for the main Nginx config and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` for the default site config.

There is a option in these config files called `client_max_body_size`. Change this to a value like *20m* to allow a upload limit of 20 megabyte.